# Vector cube question

Tags: geometry

How would I express the following vector in this cube[image]

I think AF would a+b+c

But I am not sure how to solve the other vectors.

Comment: $a+b+c=\vec{AG}$, not $\vec{AF}$, so try again.

Comment: I see then AF is perhaps a+c-b

Comment: Ok, walk the path from _A_ to _F_ for example. You go along $\bf{a}$ and then along $\rm BF=\bf{c}$. So _AF_ = _a_ + _c_. The same for the rest of the vectors.

Comment: You don't always need to use all three vectors $\vec{a}, \vec{b}, \vec{c}$.

Comment: @FernandoMartinez $a+c-b$ yields a point on the line $GF$ that isn't even on the cube. Stop guessing and start thinking about head-to-tail vector addition!

Comment: I see ja72 that makes sense

Comment: By the way, Fernando, you ask a lot of good questions.  I don't think I've seen a rep that high with nothing but questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you add vectors graphically, place the tail of the second one at the head of the first one.  Then the vector sum goes from the tail of the first to the head of the second.

You can move $\vec{a}, \vec{b},$ and $\vec{c}$ around (translate them) to get them where you need them to be, but don't rotate them.

You can also subtract two vectors.  It's the same as adding them, but turn the second one backwards before you add them.

So if you move $\vec{a}$ from $AB$ up to $EF$, you start at $A$ and end at $F$ by adding together $\vec{c} + \vec{a}$.

Can you take it from here?

Comment: I see so each vector represent length,width, and height. In a way

Comment: Yes, in a way.  It also has direction, which is critical.  $\vec{AF} = -\vec{FA},$ for example.

Comment: so CF could be -a+c

Comment: Nope.  $-\vec{a} + \vec{c}$ is either $\vec{BE}$ or $\vec{CH}.$

Answer (score 1):

I suggest thinking of it in the following way:

When you have $a$ you are moving right (the length of one side of the cube), similarly $b$ is moving to the direction "inside" the page, and $c$ is moving up.

To get from $A$ to $F$ you need to go right and up - so $\vec{AF}=a+c$.

Can you do the others ?

Comment: so c-b is CF I think

Comment: @FernandoMartinez - yes